# openFrameworks + ofVideoPlayer image tearing

Tags: c++, opengl, openframeworks

I'm using `ofVideoPlayer` and for some reason there is some flicker/tear the moment of the transitions between the videos. I've tried to change the video format, i added `ofSetVerticalSync(true);`and it stills gets that error.
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of struggle with Openframeworks and Tearing.

Basically, it depends a lot on your Hardware.

You may install drivers to force the graphic cards vsync.

It is more true if you run OF with Linux OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows certainly look into the graphics cards settings panel and experiment with different settings for vertical sync.

If you are on on OSX there are some other video players you might want to test.
http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/ofxavfvideoplayer/12770

Recently I have had the best results with the HAP codec and the hap player. It loads super quick and supports alpha channels. I would definitely try that.

https://github.com/bangnoise/ofxHapPlayer